# Disable Java version out of date prompt

Tags: windows-7, command-line, internet-explorer-9, java

We are running IE9 and Java 1.7 Update 51 (WIN7) in our environment and I am having a heck of a time getting rid of the following popup.

[image: Java Version Out of date]

Since update 55 was released, users get the following prompt when brought to a Java page.  Of course, if they hit Later, the Java app will run and the world is safe. But people hit different things and it's my job to herd the cows in the right direction.

What I found is that by adding the following Reg Key to HKCU

> HKCU\Software\AppDataLow\Software\JavaSoft\DeploymentProperties /v deployment.expiration.check.enabled /t REG_SZ /d false /f

it will suppress the prompt. So I was planning on iterating through all user profiles and adding the key. But, after a reboot, my key is deleted and on the next launch of a Java app, I will get a prompt.

I'm prepping Update 55 for my environment and would like to get rid of this prompt for future releases of Java.

I also tried to use a `deployment.properties` file with the following data inside it:

> deployment.expiration.check.enabled=false
>    deployment.expiration.decision.suppression.10.51.2=true
>    deployment.expiration.decision.10.51.2=later

I placed that file in the user directory `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment` after an installation of Java.

That didn't work either.

Answer (score 3):

I have been wrestling with that annoyance also and I discovered that the `HKCU\Software\AppDataLow\Software\JavaSoft\DeploymentProperties` registry key gets its values from the user's deployment.properties file. 
I have been deleting the file, recreating it then writing the properties/values that I want before Java loads. I have been running from the all users start up successfully on a Windows 7 32-bit and 64-bit test computer for the past two days.

Here is a PowerShell function that has worked for me:

```
Function JavaProperties
{
    $userProfile = $Env:USERPROFILE
    Remove-Item -Path "$($userProfile)\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\deployment.properties" -Force

    New-Item -Path "$($userProfile)\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment" -ItemType File -Name "deployment.properties"

    $deployFroperties = Get-ChildItem -Path "$($userProfile)\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment" -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where{$_.Name -eq "deployment.properties"} | Select -ExpandProperty FullName
    $expDecision = New-TimeSpan -Start $($(Get-Date).ToString()) -End "January 1, 2020 11:59:00 PM" | Select -ExpandProperty TotalMilliseconds
    $expDecision

    Add-Content -Path $deployFroperties -Value "deployment.expiration.decision.suppression.10.51.2=true" -Force
    Add-Content -Path $deployFroperties -Value "deployment.expiration.decision.10.51.2=later" -Force
    Add-Content -Path $deployFroperties -Value "deployment.expiration.decision.timestamp.10.51.2=$expDecision" -Force
    Add-Content -Path $deployFroperties -Force -Value "deployment.system.tray.icon=true"


}#End Function JavaProperties
```

Answer (score 0):

Well in addition some stuff I got out discovering Java web start
Decompiling
c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_66**jre\bin\plugin2\npjp2.dll**
in IDA6 Hexrays

These settings are involed:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER, SOFTWARE\AppDataLow\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\DeploymentProperties\pending
    deployment.expiration.decision.11.66.2 = update|block|later
    deployment.expiration.decision.suppression.11.66.2  true
    deployment.expiration.decision.timestamp.11.66.2    86401..18446744073709551616 (<- 0xFFFFFF FFFFFF)

HKEY_CURRENT_USER, SOFTWARE\AppDataLow\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\DeploymentProperties
    deployment.expiration.decision.11.66.2
    deployment.expiration.decision.suppression.11.66.2
    deployment.expiration.decision.timestamp.11.66.2

    deployment.webjava.enabled  false
    deployment.expiration.decision.ttl.11.66.2      86401..18446744073709551616 (<- 0xFFFFFF FFFFFF)
```

*for below windows vista leave out the "SOFTWARE\AppDataLow\" part*

so feel free to play around with this 
and you may also try these values as **enviroment settings** like this

Startbrowser.cmd

```
set deployment.expiration.decision.11.66.2=later
set deployment.expiration.decision.suppression.11.66.2=true
Firefox.exe %*
```

Okay that it.

At the end some pseudo code. Take it as hint.
And don't be to serious -in case it's confusing just ignore it.

```
BOOL __stdcall DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
    StringCompare
        ~otherStrings~ VIA  mbscmp
        ~timestamp~ VIA sscanf "%llu" (<-unsigned long long int)


GetFromEnvOrReg_Depl_pending FORALL 
    deployment.expiration.decision.11.66.2
    deployment.expiration.decision.suppression.11.66.2
    deployment.expiration.decision.timestamp.11.66.2

    deployment.expiration.decision.11.66.2 == 
        update 1
        block 2
        later 3
    if NoValidValue
        GetFromEnvOrReg_Depl FORALL 
            deployment.expiration.decision.11.66.2
            deployment.expiration.decision.suppression.11.66.2
            deployment.expiration.decision.timestamp.11.66.2



    deployment.expiration.decision.suppression.11.66.2
        true

    deployment.expiration.decision.timestamp.11.66.2


    GetFromEnvOrReg_Depl    
        deployment.webjava.enabled
            false
    if success return false

    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ unfinished
    deployment.expiration.decision.ttl.11.66.2
        ttl+604800 (or +10 if decision is 'later' )
    compare is bigger as timestamp
    if ... decision is not 'block' return false
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


    FUNC GetFromEnvOrReg_Depl_pending ( $Value )
        MSVCR100.getenv
        if success return $result

        RegOpenKeyExA
            HKEY_CURRENT_USER

            isVistaOrAbove 
                    SOFTWARE\AppDataLow\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\DeploymentProperties\pending
                    SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\DeploymentProperties\pending

        RegQueryValueExA $Value
        if success Return $result

    FUNC GetFromEnvOrReg_Depl ( $Value )
        *same* but with 
        SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\DeploymentProperties

        FUNC isVistaOrAbove
            GetVersionExA
                VersionInformation.dwPlatformId == VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT (2) &&
                VersionInformation.dwMajorVersion >= 6
```